# String comparison in bash script not working when script called from php

Tags: php, bash, character-encoding, shell-exec

I wrote a bash script that needs to handle named arguments. I want to call it with

`script.sh --dir /path/to/dir`

The script is :

```
#/usr/bin/bash
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        echo "##$1##"
        if [[ $1 == *"--"* ]]; then
                param="${1/--/}"
                declare $param="$2"
                echo "\$1 contains -- : $1"
        else
                echo "\$1 does not contain -- : $1"
        fi
        shift
done
echo $dir
exit 0
```

When called on command line it works fine :

```
$ ./genCrt.sh --dir test
##--dir## 
$1 contains -- : --dir
##test## 
$1 does not contain -- : test 
test
```

But when called from a php script, this way :  `$out = shell_exec("/path/to/script.sh --dir test");`
I get this result :

```
##--dir## 
$1 does not contain -- : --dir 
##test## 
$1 does not contain -- : test
```

I can't figure out why. I guess it might be an encoding problem but I don't really know how to check it...

[EDIT] It's not an encoding issue, I added this code

```
echo -n $1|hexdump -v
echo -n "--"|hexdump -v
```

and I get

```
##--dir##
0000000 2d2d 6964 0072                         
0000005
0000000 2d2d                                   
0000002
```

So the dashes are encoded the same way : `2d`

[/EDIT]

I'm using PHP 7.3.14-1~deb10u1, Apache/2.4.38 (Debian), Bash 5.0.3(1)-release.
Thanks

Comment: Check your logs. This could be a permisisons/SELinux issue.

Comment: Nothing in logs. And the parameter is read since I can echo it...

Comment: also tried this syntax : if [[ $1 =~ .*\-\-.* ]] , still no match !

Comment: It looks like you forgot to pass the `--dir` argument in the php code. Try with `shell_exec("/path/to/script.sh --dir test")` instead of just `"/path/to/script.sh test"`.

Comment: thanks GordonDavisson but obviously I didn't. The "--dir" string is in both the inputs and the outputs I pasted here above. [edit : ] Oh I just saw what you think that, that's what I wrote. But as shows the output I in fact passed the --dir string as well so the mistake was while writing this post, not in the code. Thank you again, I correct it now.